# compressing pdf created by office 2007

Tags: compression

So I am currently applying for jobs on my school's career website, and it has a limit of 200kb for resume's, cover letter, transcript etc.

I have my resume (docx) and its in 31kb of size. However I want to make that into a pdf so employers don't have to worry about file formats. When I "save as" a pdf using office, the pdf size jumps up to 381kb. 10 times the original size.

What can I do to keep it under my limit? I prefer not to install any pdf printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Word docx format is compressed already, hence the 31KB you're seeing.

If your resume is too large, I'd recommend removing any images that you may have, and checking whether the Save As PDF settings are embedding fonts in the document.

Comment: I don't have images. Is embedding fonts good or bad and how do I check?

Comment: Embedding fonts, as it says on the tin, will embed fonts into the PDF to make it look the same as you intended, instead of replacing them with similar fonts on a system that doesn't have those fonts installed. Which is why using standard Arial or Times New Roman in a resume is better if you want to keep the size down.